# Extract Month from Date field JPA

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

In my MySQL database, I have a field in a table with type "DATE" and I want to get all the lines where the month part equals to a given one.

Exemple :

```
month = 5 

Date = 5/12/1989
Date = 6/8/1978
Date = 9/9/1999
```

Here I want to get all the lines where month equals to `5`.
To do that I must use the [CriteriaBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html).

Thank you

**UPDATE :**
 I have used this and nothing happened :

```
if(criteriaMap.containsKey("month")) {
            int month = (Integer)criteriaMap.get("month");
            predicates.add(qb.equal(qb.function("MONTH", Integer.class, profileExpenseNoteRoot.get("soldDate")),month));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: As you can see, Criteria has a FIXED API, and CriteriaBuilder has no month method, therefore you have to use the "function" method to invoke some MySQL-specific SQL. Like the MONTH function

Comment: Actually, that's what I was trying to find How but I couldn't and I didn't entirely get the use of function in criteriaBuilder

Comment: function invokes ANY SQL function, with the return type, and arguments expected by that SQL function in the database. Saying "nothing happened" says nothing ... since you have the LOG there which tells you what SQL is invoked

Comment: Well I think I put the right return type and the argument for the function `MONTH` that's why I can't figure out why it doesn't work

Comment: Thats why you need to LOOK IN THE LOG at the SQL invoked!

Comment: I did ! And the SQL command is right look : `select
profileexp0_.SOLD_DATE as SOLD5_205_,
profileexp0_.TVA as TVA205_ 
from
profile_expense_note profileexp0_ 
where
 month(profileexp0_.SOLD_DATE)=5
`

Comment: And also I made sure that there's data in the table

Comment: It was a dumb error, nevermind ^^